# Why wont the pull cord retract on my honda eu20i generator?

Tags: generator, lawn-mower, engine

I had no issues with the pull cord recoil starter on my newly acquired used Honda eu20i.

Suddenly the  the pull cord stopped recoiling at all.  I figured the spring had just broke  but on removing the unit it seems there's at least some tension still in it. With a broken spring I would expect no tension.

Have you any ideas what's going on?

Also I cant see any center bolt or fixing so that I could remove the recoil mechanism and inspect the spring.

Is it possible to dismantle the recoil starter on an eu20i?

Comment: This may be better addressed over at the motor vehicle stack. https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/?newreg=24b7afc5371742e6aa94809e7d0d5942

Comment: @alaska.  That's what I thought except I checked where the other generator and lawn mower questions were located and seems they were here. Do you know how I can move it?

Comment: If it is new I would take it back, if just new you (used) look at solar mikes answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some tension? Usually with that retractor unit on the bench the spring has to be pre-tensioned sufficiently to retract the pull cord with alacrity ie not “just enough” but with speed and force.

I found that it would need the same number of turns plus 1 and you need to be carefull when doing the pre-tension as the mechanism can jump out and you might get hit...

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the problem is with the spring itself - I believe.  I took another approach and threaded the 1m rope around the unit then tensioned +1.  I recoiled  and installed it again and it worked for 2 pulls and then it appeard to slip and the rope was fully out with no tension and you could hear the coil unravel.  Theres a problem with the coil itself or its seating - I need to access inside the unit.